# contentscript, dynamic created iframe, postmessage

Tags: google-chrome-extension, content-script

I'm attempting to inject an iframe from a content script. From the content script, post a message to the iframe, without much success. This is the closest I have got. No errors/warnings in the console but it doesn't work (alert test).

**contentscript:**

```
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.setAttribute("src", "https://www.com/iframe.php");
iframe.id = "iframe01";
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(iframe);

//then I inject this "web_accessible_resources" script

var script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = chrome.extension.getURL("postMessage.js");
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
```

**postMessage.js**

```
window.postMessage({msg: "test"}, "*");
```

I've also tried

```
top.postMessage({msg: "test"}, "*");
```

And

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe01');
iframe.contentWindow.postMessage({msg: "test"}, "*");
```

EDIT: I tried to make sure the iframe was loaded before postMessage, even if I put an alert there, it would alert telling me the iframe was loaded.

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe01');
if (ifrm_prsto.contentWindow.document)
    //do postMessage
```

EDIT2: I did get it to work by moving the iframe from the contentscript to the inject.js script. Wasn't totally ideal but I do have it working now, I guess.

**iframe.php**

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(e) {alert("test");});
```

I am however able to do the reverse, talk to the parent script from the iframe.

Comment: Are you sure that the frame has been loaded when `postMessage` is used? Have you tried to inject the script instead of excuting a content script?

Comment: Edited my op but I did do a check on this and it is appearing to load before the postMessage is sent off. The work around I have is by moving the iframe code to the injected script and out of the content script.

Answer (score 0):

I have the reverse problem.  I am trying to close a transparent iFrame from within the iframe, which requires the content script to locate the the iframe and remove it from the page.

I have been trying various forms of using:

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest(function())
var port = chrome.extension.connect({})
var port = chrome.tabs.connect({})
```

However the iframe has a weird context and has trouble using any of these methods.  So far the best I have is that the iFrame can open a port and send a message to the background script, which might then be able to send a message back to the content script on the same tab.